# Laravel - How to retrieve all subscriptions with metadata from Stripe

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-cashier, stripe-payments

I am creating a Stripe subscription with Laravel cashier. I have successfully created a subscription in Stripe with metadata. How to retrieve all subscriptions (with metadata) of a customer.?

Below is the code that creates the subscription

```
$request->user()->newSubscription('main', $plan->stripe_plan)->withMetadata(['wcda_reference' => $reference])->create($request->stripeToken);
```

Tried below code to retrieve but its listing from my database - not from Stripe API

```
$request->user()->subscriptions();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$request->user()->asStripeCustomer()->subscriptions;
```

It returns a list of user's subscriptions.

Here is the Stripe API doc of the response: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve

Comment: What happens if a user cancels a subscription and never renews it? Will this subscription appear in this list? And how do I check if a user has an active subscription right now?

Comment: @TyomaInagamov it returns a list of [subscription objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object) if any. it also includes canceled ones: `subscription->status === 'canceled'`.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It really helped me out!

Comment: By the way, I've found a bug that if user wants to buy a subscription after he immediately cancelled it, it doesn't show up at `$user->asStripeCustomer()->subscriptions`. However, the payment succeeded and at stripe dashboard I can see that user has an active subscription. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
$all_subs_ids = [];
$allSubs = \Stripe\Subscription::all(['limit' => 10, 'status' => 'active']); foreach($allSubs->autoPagingIterator() as $allSub) {
    array_push($all_subs_ids, $allSub->id);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).